# Residuals of continuity not converging

Tags: fluid-mechanics, simulation, turbines, ansys

I'm simulating a turbine.

The convergence of solution is monitored by checking the residuals of the numerically solved governing equations. 
The "viscous-spalarat-almaras" model is used, and used air with constant density. Pressure-velocity coupled scheme and pressure based solver are selected.

According to the following figures, torque is increasing but the residual of continuity does not decrease and is almost constant. T

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]
<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

[image: Image 3]
<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

Is there any problem?

According to monitored torque, the solution is not converged.

Comment: If you're sure your simulation really has a steady state solution, then you might want to play with relaxation parameters or check your grid quality.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks your answer,
There is many papers that is used steady state.
How to play? Do I decrease URF(under-relaxation factors)? Momentum and pressure URF   are 0.2 in this run, respectively.
How to check mesh? I am performing different mesh and also, I am using adaption option in fluent. Do you have another suggestions?
I am grateful that guide me about this cases.

Comment: Now I understand that second figure is not torque but it is total torque coefficient. How do I monitor the torque?

Comment: What kind of turbine? the constant air density assumption might be incorrect.

Comment: air turbine, namely, wells turbine

Comment: It is mentioned that flow is incompressible in many papers. 
I am grateful that guide me more

Comment: To answer this we'd need to know how you set up your model, what your boundary conditions are etc.